# JPA how to definie which persistence unit use for specific entity class

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I was working with app, where multiple db connections is needed. I've created AbstractDao.class where I want to use EntityManager defined for specific Entity class. In my example I have defined two types of entities: OracleEmployeeEntity and MySQLEmployeeEntity. How to define EntityManager in AbstractDao to use correct instance for correct entities? Below my current config, when I was running test with usage two dbs NullPointerException is thrown.

AbstractDao.class:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractDao<T, K extends Serializable> implements IDao<T, K> {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

private Class<T> domainClass;

@Override
public T save(T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getOne(K id) {
    return entityManager.getReference(getDomainClass(), id);
}

[...]
```

persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.database.tests.entities.OracleEmployeeEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test_user"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test_user"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="db1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.database.tests.entities.OracleEmployeeEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test_user"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test_user"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="db2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.database.tests.entities.MySqlEmployeeEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees"/>
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Part of test:

```
    //db variable defined in @Before (jUnit)
    @Test
    public void testShouldCompareDataFromDifferentDatabases() {
    //given
    MySQLDatabase mySQLDatabase = new MySQLDatabase();

    //when
    long oracleCount = db.getEmployeeDao().count();
    long mySqlCount = mySQLDatabase.getEmployeeDao().count();

    //then
    assertNotEquals(oracleCount, mySqlCount);
}
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.database.base.AbstractDao.count(AbstractDao.java:74)
at com.example.database.tests.assertions.JpaTest.testShouldCompareDataFromDifferentDatabases(JpaTest.java:166)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at com.example.core.tests.testRunners.core.CustomRunAfters.evaluate(CustomRunAfters.java:39)
at com.example.core.tests.testRunners.ParallelTestClassRunner.run(ParallelTestClassRunner.java:36)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: detailed exception please. What server do You use? What kind of application / environment ?

Comment: stacktrace updated with part of test